# Implied do construct repeating scalar values in an array constructor

Tags: arrays, fortran

I'm trying to figure out why the placement of a scalar before a do construct inside an array constructor produces the answer it does.

I understand the do construct in general, that `(/(i,i=1,5)/)` is equivalent to `(/1,2,3,4,5/)`.

```
real, dimension(4) :: a
integer :: i
a=(/(50,i,i=1,2)/)
```

This produces the array `50.0000000, 1.00000000, 50.0000000, 2.00000000`.  At best I would expect an error because the step size doesn't produce enough values to fill the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array produced with multiple `50`s is the expected one.

Part of the question text does not match what happens with the code:

> the placement of a scalar before a do construct inside an array constructor

In `[(50,i,i=1,2)]` (using Fortran 2003 `[...]` for clarity) the scalar value `50` is not "before" the implied do but is a clear part of it.  This can be compared with

```
a = [50, (i,i=1,3)]
```

which would result in the constructed array `[50, 1, 2, 3]`.

The formal syntax for an array constructor's implied do is

> ( *ac-value-list* , *ac-implied-do-control* )

so it can be seen that multiple values can be part of the range of the implied do control even though it is common for a single value only to be used.  With such multiple values they are all evaluated for each iteration of the implied do (and `50` evaluates the same each time) and used in the array construction.

Comment: Firstly, thank you.
So just to make sure I understand, what it's doing is making an array using (50, i) for i=1 and 2, resulting in (50, 1, 50, 2), and if I wanted to have the 50 separate to the implied do, I'd do `a = [50, (i,i=1,3)]`?

Comment: Correct on both parts.